# How to drop multiple columns based on their correlation with another column in the data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have a large data frame that I am cleaning for a machine learning linear regression model. I want to drop the columns that have a correlation with my dependent variable below .5 and above -.5. What is the best way to accomplish this in as little code as possible? Here's an example of a failed attempt I'm trying to work out:

```
df.drop(df.loc[:, df.corrwith(df['saleprice'])] <.5 & > -.5, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with `inclusive=False` and for drop columns change logic - get all columns which not match mask by invering it by `~`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'a':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'b':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'c':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'saleprice':[5,3,6,9,2,4],

})

df1 = df.loc[:, ~df.corrwith(df['saleprice']).between(-.5, .5, inclusive=False)]
print (df1)
   c  saleprice
0  1          5
1  3          3
2  5          6
3  7          9
4  1          2
5  0          4
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.corrwith(df['saleprice']).between(-.5, .5, inclusive=False))
a             True
b             True
c            False
saleprice    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: I'm doing my best to follow your suggestions but getting the following error:  IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

Comment: @DylanLunde - Not some `[]` is wrong? because here is working nice.

Comment: @DylanLunde - Can you test what return `print (df.corrwith(df['saleprice']).between(-.5, .5, inclusive=False))`? something similar like `detail` in my answer?

Comment: df2 = df.loc[:, ~df.corrwith(df1['saleprice']).between(-.5, .5, inclusive=False)] .           print(df2)                                                                                                     example_column
0                    0
1                    1
2                    0
3                    1
4                    1                                                                                                          Now it's working but with only 1 column. I forgot to mention that the correlation column could be part of a different df if that's important

Comment: correct still not working. I was editing my comments to better clarify the status. I'm still new to stack overflow and formatting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206073/discussion-between-jezrael-and-dylan-lunde).